# Python: Socket communication with Arduino MKR1000 not working properly

Tags: python, sockets, arduino, wifi, serversocket

I got a system where I would send a command from my host computer using Python Socket (the computer is the server) and the MKR1000 (client) would send back information depends on the command sent.

Unfortunately, the bidirectional communication is unstable. I can guarantee the MKR1000 received the command and (maybe) sending information back, but for some reason, my host computer would not receive the command.

Anyway, this is my first time trying out socket, so I would like some guru to review my code and maybe spot the mistake in here? Thanks a lot.

Python:

```
import socket
import time

def coor2bytes(coor_fnc):
    coorByte = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

    if (coor_fnc[0] >= 0):
        coorByte[0] = (coor_fnc[0] >> 8) & 0xFF # High byte of X
        coorByte[1] = coor_fnc[0] & 0xFF # Low byte of X
    else:
        coor_fnc[0] = coor_fnc[0]*(-1)
        coorByte[0] = (coor_fnc[0] >> 8) & 0xFF # High byte of X
        coorByte[0] = coorByte[0] ^ 0x80
        coorByte[1] = coor_fnc[0] & 0xFF # Low byte of X

    if (coor_fnc[1] >= 0):
        coorByte[2] = (coor_fnc[1] >> 8) & 0xFF # High byte of Y
        coorByte[3] = coor_fnc[1] & 0xFF # Low byte of Y
    else:
        coor_fnc[1] = coor_fnc[1]*(-1)
        coorByte[2] = (coor_fnc[1] >> 8) & 0xFF # High byte of X
        coorByte[2] = coorByte[2] ^ 0x80
        coorByte[3] = coor_fnc[1] & 0xFF # Low byte of X

    if (coor_fnc[2] >= 0):
        coorByte[4] = (coor_fnc[2] >> 8) & 0xFF # High byte of Phi
        coorByte[5] = coor_fnc[2] & 0xFF # Low byte of Phi
    else:
        coor_fnc[2] = coor_fnc[2]*(-1)
        coorByte[4] = (coor_fnc[2] >> 8) & 0xFF # High byte of Phi
        coorByte[4] = coorByte[4] ^ 0x80
        coorByte[5] = coor_fnc[2] & 0xFF # Low byte of Phi

    return coorByte

def bytes2coor(byte_fnc):
    receivedCoor_fnc = [0, 0, 0]

    receivedCoor_fnc[0] = ((-1)**(byte_fnc[0]>>7)) * ((byte_fnc[1]) | (((byte_fnc[0]&0x7f)<<8)))
    receivedCoor_fnc[1] = ((-1)**(byte_fnc[2]>>7)) * ((byte_fnc[3]) | (((byte_fnc[2]&0x7f)<<8)))
    receivedCoor_fnc[2] = ((-1)**(byte_fnc[4]>>7)) * ((byte_fnc[5]) | (((byte_fnc[4]&0x7f)<<8)))

    return receivedCoor_fnc


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)


    s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 1234)) # bind(ip, port)
    print("Done binding.")
    s.listen(2)

    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    print(f"Connection from {address} has been established!")

    clientsocket.settimeout(1)

    while True:
        print();
        print("What you want to do?")
        print("0. Send target")
        print("1. Get current coordinate")
        print("2. Set current coordinate (not yet implement)")
        try:
            a = int(input("I choose: "))
        except Exception:
            print("Error.")
            a = -1;

        if (a == 0):
            coor = [0, 0, 0]
            try:
                coor[0] = int(input("X: "))
                coor[1] = -int(input("y: "))
                coor[2] = int(input("phi: "))

                coorByte = coor2bytes(coor)

                clientsocket.send(bytes([0]))
                clientsocket.send(bytes(coorByte))
                print("I already sent the target.")

            except Exception:
                    print("Error.")

        elif (a == 1):
            receive = 0
            while (not receive):
                try:
                    clientsocket.send(bytes([1]))
                    bytesReceived = []
                    full_msg = []

                    while (len(full_msg) < 8):
                        bytesReceived = clientsocket.recv(8)
                        for x in range(len(bytesReceived)):
                            full_msg.append(bytesReceived[x])

                    receivedCoor = bytes2coor(full_msg)
                    print("coordinate received: " + str(receivedCoor))
                    receive = 1
                except socket.timeout:
                    print("Time out. Will try again.")

        elif (a == 2):
            setCoor = [0, 0, 0]
            try:
                setCoor[0] = int(input("X: "))
                setCoor[1] = -int(input("y: "))
                setCoor[2] = int(input("phi: "))

                setcoorByte = coor2bytes(setCoor)

                clientsocket.send(bytes([2]))
                clientsocket.send(bytes(setcoorByte))

                print("I already sent the new coordinate.")
            except Exception:
                    print("Error.")



        else:
            print("Not yet implement.")
```

Arduino:

```
#include <WiFi101.h>
#include <SPI.h>

// To connect to the server on laptop
char ssid[] = "iPhone";
char pass[] = "00000000";
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;

IPAddress server(172,20,10,3);
WiFiClient client;


// Random variable
int a, i, j, k, m;
byte buf0[7];
byte buf1[7];
byte buf2[7];

long start = millis();
int elapsedTime = 0;
int timeout = 0;

void setup() {
// put your setup code here, to run once:
//  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial1.begin(115200);


//  status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

  while (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
  }

  j = client.connect(server, 1234);
  while (j != 1)  {
    j = client.connect(server, 1234);
  }
}

void loop()
{
  if (client.available()) {   
    a = client.read();
    Serial.print("I got: ");
    Serial.println(a);

    if (a == 0) { // Send new target to Due
      Serial.println("I send target.");
      j = 0;
      start = millis();
      while(j<6) {
        elapsedTime = millis() - start;

        if (elapsedTime > 1000) {
          timeout = 1;
          break;
        }

        if (client.available()>0) {
          buf0[j] = client.read();
          Serial.println(buf0[j]);
          j++;        
        }
      }

      if (timeout != 1) {
        Serial1.write((byte) 0);
        // Send coordinate back to Due
        for (i = 0; i<6; i++) {
          Serial1.write(buf0[i]);
        }
      } else {
        timeout = 0;
      }

    } else if (a == 1) {
      // Get the coordinate from the Due
      Serial.println("I receive coordinate.");
      Serial1.write((byte) 1);
      k = 0;
      start = millis();
      while(k < 6) {
        elapsedTime = millis() - start; 

        if (elapsedTime > 1000) {
          timeout = 1;
          break;
        }

        if (Serial1.available() > 0) {
          buf1[k] = Serial1.read();
          Serial.println(buf1[k]);
          k++;          
        }      
      }

      if (timeout != 1) {
        for (i=0;i<6;i++)  {
          client.write(buf1[i]);
          delay(10);
        }

        client.write((byte) 0);  // fill in the blank size
        delay(10);
        client.write((byte) 0);
      } else {
        timeout = 0;
      }

//        for (int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
//          client.write((byte) 0);
//        }

    } else if (a == 2) { // set the current coordinnate to be something else.
      Serial.println("I set coordinate.");     
      m = 0;
      while(m<6) {
        if (client.available()>0) {
          buf2[m] = client.read();
          Serial.println(buf2[m]);
          m++;
        }
      }

      Serial1.write((byte) 2);
      // Send coordinate back to Due
      for (i = 0; i<6; i++) {
        Serial1.write(buf2[i]);
      }

    } else if (a == 3) { // identify yourself
      Serial.println("Identify myself.");
      client.write((byte) 1);
    }
  }
}
```

If you have time to read through the Arduino code, then you would see that I actually have serial communication between my MKR and Due too. I also can guarantee that the MKR can receive all those data from the Due and not stuck in some infinite loop.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so for some reason if I added a delay right after the MKR connecting to WiFi, before connecting to the server, then everything just works.